# Cannot update - PPAs do not have release files

Tags: software-installation

```
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons2/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that these two repositories have not yet been updated for 18.04.  You could try editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` to replace `bionic` with `artful` or whatever is the latest version shown.

If you click on your links in the question and then click `dists`, you will see which versions are available.